# C# Out of Memory when trying to change the image in a picture box

Tags: c#, exception, out-of-memory

I have been doodling around with C# designing a slideshow program for in house advertising style tv's etc.

Basically i have a form that initially takes values to a network folder with a few jpg's then runs a setup function to get the files from the directory path then starts 2 timers. 1 timer is a rotate image timer. and the other being update timer to re check if the files have changed in the folder.

Everything it tried to set the image of the picture in my rotate tick timer function it will throw an "out of memory" exception (on the first 'tick').

i have researched as much as i can, i feel a little lost as to why it running out of memory, my machine has plenty of physical memory and the program doesn't even seem heavy to me.

Any direction would be valuable.

Code Below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace MarketingImagesSS
{
    public partial class Slideshow : Form
    {
        public Menu frmMenu { get; set; }

        int counter = 0;
        string[] images;
        Image image;
        public Slideshow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tmrUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tmrRotate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pxbxImages.Image.Dispose();
            image = Image.FromFile(images[counter]);
        }

        private void setup(string directory)
        {
            images = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
            image = Image.FromFile(images[counter]);
            pxbxImages.Image = image;
            counter++;
        }

        public void Slideshow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string directoryPath = frmMenu.fPath;
            setup(directoryPath);
            //tmrUpdate.Start();
            tmrRotate.Start();
        }

        private void pxbxImages_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException`, [according to documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx), occurs because either `a) The file does not have a valid image format.` -or- `b) GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.`. Did you verify those?

Comment: You should call `image.Dispose()` before `image = Image.FromFile(images[counter]);` in `tmrRotate_Tick`. You are loading many images but not disposing them.

Comment: Are you sure that there are only images in that folder? As @Sach mentioned, this could cause this kind of exception. If there are other file types, you should use file verification.

Comment: `System.Drawing`, eww, this API is apparently did not support some image formats as Sach stated. you had to try something else, you can find nice one on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ImageProcessing).

Comment: Currently the folder has only 2 files in it with basically identical formatting IE , Both JPG, Same Res, Pixel Depth etc. they only differ in file size. of a like 150kb.

@mjwills I'm calling image.dispose in the rotate tick on the picturebox.image, i also added the dispose to just the image and it still gives me that out of memory exception on the first change.

Comment: `I'm calling image.dispose in the rotate tick on the picturebox.image` That is not sufficient since you are not assigning `image` to `pxbxImages.Image` in the tick. That being said, it is not the cause of your immediate problem since you have now revealed the issue is on the *first* change.

Comment: Never call Dispose on `picturebox.image` directly. Copy a reference to the object, set `picturebox.image` to null, and _then_ dispose the image from the copied reference, otherwise you'll get an `ObjectDisposedException` when the picture box repaints.

Comment: Thank you to everyone here, for helping me fix this issue. I used a bit of everything and have finished the project about a week ago, i just wanted to let you know.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add following method :

```
     bool IsValidImg(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Image newImg = Image.FromFile(filename))
            { }
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

then in your code add this condition (if image.fromfile works fine or not) :

```
     private void tmrRotate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidImg(images[counter])) <--- img exist condition
             image = Image.FromFile(images[counter]);
```

To prevent getting index out of array exception you also need to be sure counter is not more than the count of your images in the directory path:

```
       if (IsValidImage(images[counter]) &&  images.Length<=counter)
```

Comment: This code disposes the actual picture box... not its image. Also, you're loading the image twice in a row for no reason.

Comment: @nathan , i compiled your code , another problem is image.from file pick .xls file too , and another exception is index out of array exception ...

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad Yeah i hadn't quite finished it but i once i got over this hump i tidied everything up.